# Correct usage of want

Tags: word-usage

One of the meanings of want is **to lack something**

But I am confued regarding its use in a sentence. Which of the following sentence is correct?

> He doesn't **want** courage.
>
> He doesn't **want in** courage.

Comment: If by *sth* you mean *something*, please spell out the actual word. (I edited your question to make that change.)

Answer (score 2):

The first is probably "correct," but you would not say it. Although "*a house*" could "*want a better roof*", a human's desires are also expressed through a different sense of the verb *to want*, so there's a real ambiguity there: does your subject *not desire* courage? Or does he simply *lack* it?

To disambiguate this construction, you would instead say: "He doesn't **want for** courage", which firmly expresses the lack. Note that depending on the context this construction feels a little formal or literary.